# Prohibit app from being quit via the recent apps list

Tags: ios, process-management

Is it possible to write an app that cannot be quit through the system tray, without jailbreaking?

Comment: an app cannot be closed?? why such thing should exist?

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode. that is just an IDE.

Comment: @xlc, isnt that obvious? World Domination!

Answer (score 2):

No.  Apple specifies this behavior is not allowed.  It's notoriously difficult to nail down Apple on it's interface specification, but [based on what it says about handling multitasking events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH18-SW2), it seems unlikely that Apple would tolerate dorking with it's system controls on the subject.